# Use of a Collection object to generalize HashMap

Tags: java

I am doing a small project of reading delimited files into columns and displays them. Now i want a column class that is basically a wrapper arround a HashMap, but there is one problem, I don't know the second generic data type until the Columns constructor is called out. The constructor takes an enum with data type argument, like the below:

```
private enum DataTypes{
    NONE, INTEGER, STRING, DATE
}
```

what I have in mind is create the Column class field as a Collection, then I could initialize it when the constructor is called, like the below:

```
private class Column {
    Collection values;

    public Column(DataTypes type){
        determineType(type);
    }

    private void determineType(DataTypes type){

        switch(type){

        case NONE:      this.values = (Collection) new HashMap<Integer, StringBuilder>();
                        break;

        case INTEGER:   this.values = (Collection) new HashMap<Integer, Integer>();
                        break;

        case STRING:    this.values = (Collection) new HashMap<Integer, StringBuilder>();
                        break;

        case DATE:      this.values = (Collection) new HashMap<Integer, Date>();
                        break;

            }

        }
    }
```

My question is why do I have to cast it to the collection type (as eclipse force me) and does it mean that I cannot use any methods of HashMap?

Also is there a better aproach or maybe design pattern for a situation like that, and what could be improved? Is there anything that could go wrong with this apraoch later on like for example when adding a value as I feel that I would need to have an overloaded function for each data type to add a value.

Sorry for such a long list of questions, but I just got little experience in actuall projects and design and need a "little" guidance. (University projects are small with variables like a,b,c,x,y etc)

Thanks:)

EDIT

After a whole day of searching and asking this very badly written question I have found the Strategy design pattern is what I need, i will post the code later.

Comment: Instead of doing all this can't you just have a `Map<String, Object>`?

Comment: Because If i made a logic mistake somewhere and put not the type I wanted as the value it would go through, and then I would sit for hours and think why my program gives wrong output:) I prefer for error straight away. The Dimi answer is what I was looking for:)

Comment: Yeah, that's right. The only problem is that you won't be able to **PUT** anything in this map. So it's next to useless I guess.

Comment: I know this is why I asked for aproaches as I saw this problem coming...

Comment: Where have you asked the approaches? In the last comment you said, "The Dimi answer is what I was looking for:)". I am just telling you that with that approach you won't be able to **PUT** anything in the map.

Comment: The Dimi answer was a syntax I did't know and was looking for. I asked for aproach after the code part of my question. But finally I found an answer to my question.

Answer (score 1):

HashMap doesn't extend Collection. So you can't assign a HashMap to a variable of type Collection.

Eclipse doesn't force you to cast. You chose to accept one of the ways it suggested to make that code compile, but that doesn't mean the code is correct. It will fail at runtime, since HashMap is not a Collection.

I have a hard time understanding what this Column should represent. What would be the keys and the values of that HashMap? And, if what you actually want is not a HashMap, but a Collection, what woud be the values of the Collection?

In any case, since all the types you want to store in the Collection/Map have a single ancestor class (`Object`), you should probably use that as the type of your Collection/Map. You should also avoir storing StringBuilder. Use String instead.

Comment: The column class represents values stored in a column from a CSV file, The program will break down each line based on delimiter and put values to columns, hence I do not want to do HashMap<Integer, Object> as I might make somewhere a logic mistake and put there value that should be of different type. Also if I want to make more functionality in the future like modifying the values would StringBuilder be better? Why should StringBuider be avoided?

Comment: That doesn't answer my question: what should be the keys of the map? Your Column class, just as a collection, should probably be generic: Column<String>, Column<Date>, etc.

Comment: That was wrong I need  HashMap to store a Row Id and Value. I thought all collections have this interface or base class and I put it there just while writing the question to express an idea rather than working code. The      HashMap<Integer,?>  values; is what I was looking for

Answer (score 0):

You can declare your HashMap with the wildcard operator.

```
private class Column {
    HashMap<?,?> values;
```

Then you can initilize the Map as normal

```
 case INTEGER:   this.values = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>();
```

Only problem is that you have to cast your HashMap to `HashMap<Integer, Integer>` every time you put something to it.

Comment: Thank You for asnwer this is what I was looking for:) What do you mean by casting this?

Comment: @RobertMazurowski How are you planning on putting entries in this map? This is good just for operations like `values.size()` etc. where you are not concerned with the datatype inside the map. You can't do `values.put(...)` here!

Comment: Yes that is true, this was a little bit more of a design question, unfortunately I will have to post another better written question about that. I asked about how to aproach a problem when I don't know the data type before declaring an object.

Comment: If you want to put somehing in 'values' yo need to do `((HashMap<Integer, Integer>) values).put()`. I know this is may not be the best way

Answer (score 0):

`HashMap` is not a Collection nor does it inherit from `Collection`

The class definition of `HashMap` is:

```
public class HashMap<K,V> extends AbstractMap<K,V> implements Map<K,V>, Cloneable, Serializable
```

Therefore, `HashMap` is a `Map` and implement the `Map` interface, not `Collection`

Because all of your case statements are instantiating `HashMap`, it makes sense to change the declaration of values to a `Map` instead of `Collection:

```
Map values;
```

In addition, because all of your case statements declare `HashMap` with the key as type `Integer`, but the values as varying types, you can declare the values `Map` accordingly.

```
Map<Integer, ?> values;
```

The reason Eclipse was suggesting you cast your `HashMap` to `Collection` is because the Maps are not descendants of `Collection` and therefore the only way to satisfy the compiler would be to cast them, which would still end up with a runtime error, since they are not collections.

By making the change to the declaration of values to type `Map`, you will not only no longer need to cast, but will eliminate your runtime errors.

Comment: Thank you for your answer dear sir:). I understand my big mistake now:)